# Is there a difference between poached and steamed chicken?

Tags: chicken, steaming, poaching

I'm planning to make chicken sandwiches and was wondering what the difference is when chicken is steamed vs poached. I know the technique for both but was wondering if steaming was meant to leave the chicken more juicy (or vise versa), or are they much the same? 
Recipes call for one of the other and I'm curious if I can substitute!

Comment: You might be better off asking only your last question "*Can you substitute poached and steamed chicken for each other?*" Your main question is a matter of opinion and would be considered off-topic. I recommend you consider redrafting your question.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited. I don't think it really changes the meaning substantially, and now there's really no reason to close it.

Answer (score 4):

I would say its a matter of personal preference.  One method or the other doesn't mean your chicken will turn out jucier, either of those methods can dry chicken out if not done properly.  For your application, just cook the chicken how ever you enjoy it the best whether its those methods listed, grilling, frying, etc.  As long as you cook the meat properly it will stay juicy and tender.